# JqueryUI draggable on a sortable and also over another element

Tags: draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm not able to define a draggable element inside a sortable to be moved inside the same sortable list and also out from the sortable to another element

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where is your source code? I can't say anything else about this right now than "you're doing something wrong".

Comment: i don't know how to do it, so i haven't a source

Comment: check google first. This site is meant to help you when you run into bugs, or can't get your (already existing) code to work, not to ask for complete solutions to your problem.